# Algorithm for building an equation from a list of numbers using basic operators (+,-,*,/)

Tags: algorithm, equation

### I am struggling to find a smart/creative way to approach this problem instead of a brute force algorithm. Any insights that could allow me to view this problem in a different light would be greatly appreciated. Any language can be used.

Given a sequence of numbers, it is sometimes possible to place the basic operations of =, +, −, ×, and ÷ between those number to build a complete, correct equation. For instance, the sequence [2, 3, 8, 4, 22] can be made into an equation by putting the symbols in the following places:

2 + 3 × 8 − 4 = 22

Note how the order of operations is followed. Write a program that will build such a number sentence, given the list of numbers. An ideal solution would allow the numbers to be specified on the command line, but prompting the user for a list is also acceptable. If no true sentence can be found, print such a message to the user. Assume only one = will be used (allowing for multiple equal signs makes the assignment a lot harder, but is fun!)

You may present the sentence using prefix, infix, or postfix operators.

Sample Output

Note that some of these sequences could form multiple sentences. Only one need be printed.

$ assignment -4 1 2 3 4

1 - 2 = 3 - 4

$ assignment -4 1 1 1

1 / 1 = 1

$ assignment -4 0 18 1 2 1 1

0 / 18 = 1 - 2 + 1 * 1

$ assignment -4 2 2 2

No equation found

Comment: Brute-forcing seems right; this appears to me to be NP-Complete.

Comment: What do you consider a brute force? To me it looks like a combinatorial problem. I am not a seasoned algorithmist though, maybe there are smarter ways. I doubt though. Also you probably have better chance asking on Computer Science or Math.

Comment: +1 for brute forcing it. Unless you expect to get more than 12 numbers as input, I think your focus should be on correctly evaluating a mathematical expression, in accordance with the rules of precedence.